# Exchange 2016 Incoming Queue

Tags: exchange

Is it possible to view either using powershell or queue viewer a queue of external emails waiting to be delivered internally?

We had our HDD fill so all external emails coming in backed up and I would like to know a rough status of how many are left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we need to start with a general knowledge how email routing is done. So if an external server is sending emails to you, he checked the MX record and then find the server to send the email to. If this would be your Exchange server (and not an Antivirus / AntiSpam Server or some other Server (e.g. SmartHost) which is in front of your server) the remote server would try to send that email directly to your Exchange server. However as your Exchange Server was not having enough HD space, your Exchange Server should give the remote server the following error message:

```
Server Response: '452 4.4.5 Insufficient disk space; try again later',
```

However the remote side (and not you) will decide when an email is triggered again. So if the remote side thinks, that it is a clever idea to try it again after 15min and then again after 15min before they finally gave up, you might  never receive that email if you didn´t fixed the space issue before the 2nd attempt was done. In that case the user who send that email will get an error message (if the remote admin do not build some strange filter rules). However if the remote mail server (default setup) is configured to re-try it again after 24h you might still get most of the email during the next delivery attempt. That means the emails waiting on an external server couldn´t be monitored by you (if would be possible to check an Antivirus / Antispam server which is in front of your Exchange Server, if you are running such a construct). However if you need to check your MS Exchange Server (keep noted that the below will show ALL queues) then you can do that via:

```
Get-Queue -Server $env:computername
```

*Offtopic:
By the way there is a cost free monitoring solution called [Nagios](https://www.nagios.org/projects/nagios-core/) ([here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/linux/287-nagios-core-3-x-installation-guide-on-debian-8-x-jessie.html) is a short installation howto which you can use to begin with that solution, its running on Debian, so you do not need an Windows license, only some spare hardware a Rasperry Pi might work as well for some companies if you really need to cut costs.). Its quite easy to install. It can monitor your Exchange server via some plugins (see [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/nagios-monitoring.html)) and can also monitor the disk space from your exchange server and inform you via email (or 3rd party email2SMS gateway) once the space gets critically. Then (hopefully) such kind of issues do not happen again as you can jump in right in time.*